# Problema al adaptar contenido

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

Tengo creado una barra de navegación con un botón para cuando la anchura de la pantalla sea menor a `1024px`, cuando la anchura de la pantalla pase de los `1024px` el botón debe desaparecer. Esto funciona sin problemas. El problema viene en que si antes interactúo con él, cuando vuelvo a agrandar la pantalla se queda y no desaparece. Lo mismo pasa si lo dejo abierto, y pasa la pantalla por debajo de los `1024px`, este no vuelve a aparecer.

Éste es mi código:

```js
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var hamburguermenu = document.getElementById("hamburguermenu");
var cruzmenu = document.getElementById("cruzmenu");

function showmenu() {
    menu.style.display = "block";
    hamburguermenu.style.display = "none";
    cruzmenu.style.display = "inline-block";
};

function closemenu() {
    menu.style.display = "none";
    hamburguermenu.style.display = "inline-block";
    cruzmenu.style.display = "none";
};
```

```css
#hamburguermenu {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin: 2vh 5vw;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    margin-right: 8vw;
    min-height: 40px;
}

#cruzmenu {
    width: 12vw;
    height: 7vh;
    background-color: green;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin: 2vh 5vw;
    float: right;
    display: none;
}

#menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
    #hamburguermenu {
        display: none;
    }
    #cruzmenu {
        display: none;
    }
    #menu {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="hamburguermenu" onclick="showmenu();">
    <div id="barra1"></div>
    <div id="barra2"></div>
    <div id="barra3"></div>
</button>

<button type="button" id="cruzmenu" onclick="closemenu();">
    <div id="cruz1"></div>
    <div id="cruz2"></div>
</button>

<div id="menu">
    <a href="#">¿Quienes somos?</a>
    <a href="#">Contactanos</a>
    <a href="#">Nuestros trabajos</a>
    <a href="#">Lista de precios</a>`
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te sucede es que no has tenido en cuenta el orden de precedencia de los estilos `CSS`. Tratándose de una misma regla `CSS`, este es el orden de precedencia (de mayor a menor):

1. Reglas `CSS` con `!important`
2. Reglas `CSS` aplicadas directamente en el elemento usando la propiedad `style`
3. Reglas `CSS` declaradas directamente en el `HTML` dentro de etiquetas `<style>` o declaradas en ficheros de estilo externos al `HTML` (la que se declare más tarde o la que tenga más [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad) sobrescribe a la anterior)

Para que lo entiendas de una manera práctica, observa el siguiente snippet:

- Todos los elementos tienen aplicada la clase externa `w3-highway-orange` proveniente del fichero `CSS` `w3-colors-highway.css` que asigna el color de fondo `#e06000`.
- Los elementos 2, 3 y 4, tienen aplicada una regla con más especificidad declarada en una etiqueta `<style>` de la página con el color de fondo `#FF0000` (este estilo sobrescribe el estilo anterior).
- Los elementos 3 y 4 tienen aplicada una regla declarada en su propiedad `style` que asigna el color de fondo `#0000FF` (este estilo sobrescribe el estilo anterior).
- El elemento 4 tiene aplicada la clase de `Bootstrap` `bg-success` que asigna el color de fondo `#28a745`, que sin importar que está declarada en un fichero externo, cuenta con la regla `!important` (este estilo sobrescribe el estilo anterior).

```css
.container .col {
  height: 100px;
}

.container .col:nth-child(n + 2) {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-colors-highway.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col w3-highway-orange">1</div>
    <div class="col w3-highway-orange">2</div>
    <div class="col w3-highway-orange" style="background-color: #0000FF">3</div>
    <div class="col w3-highway-orange bg-success" style="background-color: #0000FF">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Teniendo en cuenta este orden de precedencia, cuando aplicas con `JavaScript` la propiedad `display`, esta se declarará en la propiedad `style` de los elementos y **primará sobre cualquier declaración que hayas realizado en el fichero `CSS`**. En vez de asignar estilos con `JavaScript`, podrías añadir o eliminar una clase usando [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).